# Show only conflict resolution history in git

Tags: git

How can I view history of completed conflict resolutions in a branch in git? I only want to see the files which had conflicts, which have been resolved. If a file had several sequential conflict resolutions, I would like to see them all listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no metadata related to conflicts in a git revision. You would need to merge the parents of a merge revision, then compare with the original merge revision.... any differences there would (in an ideal world) be related to conflict resolution. Thanks go to @jthill for great insight.

Comment: No real need to check which files conflicted, just check out one parent, merge the other, then if there's any conflicts at all diff against the committed merge result. That'll show you all conflict resolutions.

Comment: Well... that's actually correct. It even covers the case of modifications on non-conflicted files that had to be modified anyway. Great insight, @jthill

Answer (score 0):

Like @eftshift0 says I think you do have to do a `git merge` command to see the files which are conflicting. You may want to first create a temporary branch first.

Then you can then do `git merge yourbranch && git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`, which will given you the names of the conflicted files. Then delete your branch afterwards.